# python interactive console in debugger is not "interactive"

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, console, pydev

I am running Pydev 2.7.3 with Eclipse 1.5.  I'm trying to use the interactive console with the debugger (i.e. what I would like to do is insert a breakpoint in a file, run the file up to that breakpoint, then muck around with stuff in the interactive debugger).  It seems like what I am trying to do fits this exactly: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debug_console.html

But the interactive console does not DO anything.  It prints "pydev debugger: starting", and any prints from before the breakpoint in my file, but when I try to type commands and execute them it is not responsive.  It just advances one line and does nothing when I hit enter.

What's the deal? Or how can I start looking under the hood to figure out what is going on here?

EDIT
To be clear, I'm looking for the kind of functionality described here:
[Jump into a Python Interactive Session mid-program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925832/jump-into-a-python-interactive-session-mid-program?rq=1)
[Interactive console using Pydev in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271625/interactive-console-using-pydev-in-eclipse?rq=1)

but the "interactive" console that appears (as indicated in the answers to those questions) is not interactive.

EDIT: Problem seems to have resolved.  No explanation other than restarting.

Comment: What libraries are you using?  Some patterns break the interactive console, because the console does real time code analysis and introspection to support the auto-complete functionality, and code that does funky stuff with properties and the like can break things due to side-effects.

Comment: well...now it works.  not sure what changed, but after closing eclipse, restarting (and doing a bunch of other random and seemingly unrelated stuff)...i now have an *interactive* interactive console.  i have no explanation, but i'll return here if it continues to misbehave.  maybe it was something i had loaded before that was breaking the interactive console?  no idea.